# Automatic converting loops into streams in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, java-8

Is there a way to refactor a loop over collections into Collection.forEach using refactoring or code inspection (problem severity) using eclipse ?

example :
howto convert this :

```
for(Person person : personenListe) {
    System.out.println(person);
}
```

into this :

```
personenListe.forEach(System.out::println);
```

using a refactoring action in eclipse ?

Comment: write it by your hand. That how you should learn.

Comment: hm... intellij has it, most probably just a setting in Eclipse

Comment: This is not the meaning of the question. I know very well howto do by hand, but I like to have a efficient approach to migrate a JAVA7 project and this is only a easy sample. Mentoining the settings is like redirecting the answer to the same question. Not helpfull :-)

Comment: I love IntelliJ really. Its better then Eclipse in my opinion too. But I need to migrate a project within a team using eclipse. (Where is the comment gone, for that I answered this ? )

Comment: I dont think eclipse has that feature .

Comment: I fear too. Inlining anonymous Functional interfaces it can manage, but this one not.

Comment: Has anyone opened a feature request for it? Which version are you trying this on?

Comment: The newest. Downloaded last week.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to exist yet but there is a bug created for it [#431967](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=431967)